# Does "Wallch" work with Ubuntu 18.04? Or another app?

Tags: desktop-background

We'd like a daily change of wallpaper, using our own picture folder. We're using Ubuntu 18.04LTS.
Wallch seems at first sight to be the answer, but I'm only seeing recent reviews that it doesn't work at all well.

Or is there another which does the same job? I can find plenty which download from the web, but we'd prefer our own memories to look at.
I'm a basic Ubuntu user, so very shy of stuff which might upset the machinery.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The `variety` app is actively developed and available in the Ubuntu repositories. It allows use of local files and/or online services.
It can be installed from the Software Centre or using the command line:

```
sudo apt install variety
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks useful. For some reason it didn't appear when I looked in the Software Centre - must have been using wrong search terms!